My availability date shifted in the middle of the interview process, when do I disclose it?
I currently have a job that is quite boring, but otherwise great. Because of that, I've been looking around for something else, but without any pressing need to leave ASAP. I am currently in an interview process with a company that is quite promising, and that I would be excited to work for. The interview is a long, multistep process, and I'm somewhere in the middle now. It's been going for 3 weeks, and I assume that another 3 weeks are ahead of me.
Unfortunately, due to unforeseen life changes, in the coming months, I will need a steady source of income. Changing jobs, and then losing it (either during the trial period, or not having my initial 6-month contract extended) is not something I can deal with it. That's why my initially communicated 2-month-from-receiving-the-offer availability period is no longer feasible.
What do I do in this situation? Is it reasonable to finish the interview, and at the last step say that unfortunately I can only start in 6 months? Or do I communicate this immediately (and possibly get a bye-bye)?

Is there any reason not to be honest with them? It can only frustrate them to offer you a job and you're not available. Better to be on their qualified candidates list.

You'd have to face the possibility of "getting a bye-bye" regardless.
3 weeks sunk on a 6 week recruitment process isn't that much of an issue, especially when you were wanting 9 weeks yourself between the offer date and start date, and now want 26 weeks.
If life has suddenly changed and you won't be free for at least another 6 months, then you should just make your excuses now and look to bow out. If it's a good and transient excuse like a new baby, then say so and avoid any possibility of staining your chances when applying again in future.
There would also be no harm in asking whether they want to proceed and then have you on a waiting list for 6 months (plausible if it's a large company that struggles to achieve its desired volume of recruitment in a particular location), but I wouldn't expect them to hold a specific position open for 6 months, and if they're making you jump through 6 weeks of hoops then I doubt they're struggling to make up numbers either, so they may just invite you to apply again in future when they invite new applications.


Is it reasonable to finish the interview, and at the last step say
that unfortunately I can only start in 6 months? Or do I communicate
this immediately (and possibly get a bye-bye)?

It wouldn't make any sense to spring a "Oh, you remember where I said I could be available in 2 months? Yeah, it's actually 6 months now." surprise at the last minute, assuming you actually want the job.
Tell them now. Explain why this change happened.
Maybe it will matter, maybe it won't. Both sides will be better off knowing now.

Anytime time frames change, it’s in the best interest of all parties to have that communicated to all parties as soon as possible.
The closer to a deadline a notification of change is communicated, the more disruptive of plans and the less likely that they will be able to accommodate a new schedule. And both employer and employees typically have alternatives if the schedule breaks down (alternative candidate/employer or just sticking with the status quo).

Companies usually have two types of open positions.

Positions to cover somebody who is leaving or to reinforce some project that needs more resources. For this type of positions the starting date can usually not be negotiated much, since starting a month later might mean no time for knowledge transfer.
Open positions to get skilled people that will be valuable for the company. This time of recruitment is more focused on the person and less on the starting date. So starting in 6 months instead of 2 might be perfectly fine.

Depending on which type of positions you applied, the company might be more or less open to accept a later incorporation than the one initially mentioned.
Ask them, the sooner you communicate it to them the sooner you will know if they are still interested in you or not.
